# Using postgres ENUM with rails yields `PG::DatatypeMismatch`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

Trying to update the value of a Postgres ENUM column throws the following exception:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "interesting_column" is of type interesting_thing but expression is of type integer
>
> LINE 1: UPDATE "interesting_table" SET "interesting_column" = 0, "updated_a...
>
> HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

```
InterestingTable.first.update_attributes!(normal_column: 'food')
  # => perfectly fine
InterestingTable.first.update_attributes!(interesting_column: 'foo')
  # => above exception
```

Here is the migration to create the table:

```
class CreateInterestingTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE normal_thing AS ENUM ('food', 'water', 'shelter');
      CREATE TYPE interesting_thing AS ENUM ('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
    SQL

    create_table :interesting_tables do |t|
      t.column :normal_column, :normal_thing
      t.column :interesting_column, :interesting_thing
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :interesting_tables
    execute 'DROP TYPE normal_thing'
    execute 'DROP TYPE interesting_thing'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that while the column has the correct type in the database, active record will try to interpret it as `integer`. You can verify that by running:

```
InterestingTable.columns
# => [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007f7567f82260
#      @coder=nil,
#      @default=nil,
#      @limit=nil,
#      @name="id",
#      @null=false,
#      @precision=nil,
#      @primary=true,
#      @scale=nil,
#      @sql_type="integer",
#      @type=:integer>,
#     #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007f7568075690
#      @coder=nil,
#      @default=nil,
#      @limit=nil,
#      @name="normal_column",
#      @null=true,
#      @precision=nil,
#      @primary=false,
#      @scale=nil,
#      @sql_type="normal_thing",
#      @type=nil>,
#     #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007f7568075668
#      @coder=nil,
#      @default=nil,
#      @limit=nil,
#      @name="interesting_column",
#      @null=true,
#      @precision=nil,
#      @primary=false,
#      @scale=nil,
#      @sql_type="interesting_thing",
#      @type=:integer>]
```

Note how the type for the second column is `nil`, while that of the last one is `integer`. `String#to_i` returns `0` if your string didn't start with a number, hence you get the error that you are trying to assign `0`.

---

But why is that? The reason - `interesting_thing` contains the substring `int`, which the adapter considers an `integer`. This seems to be a long existing bug that hasn't been fixed up until rails 4.2. [The offending method.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.15/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb#L264)

---

Possible solutions:

- Migrate to rails 4.2+
- Rename your ENUM to something that wont be matched
- Monkey patch the adapter. Here is a [quick fix](https://gist.github.com/ndnenkov/34c90ad827d3fa25b89483c8a1f31cb5).